# "Access to..." or "access of..."?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions, titles, to-of

Translating a title of a paper from another language, I’m debating between

- Remote Access *to* a Computer System
- Remote Access *of* a Computer System

This is a title, so it should stand on its own, without extra context.

Which is correct? If both are valid English, what’s the difference in meaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - Remote access *of* the tech support team *to* the computer system.
> - Remote access *of* the computer system *to* data files located in cloud storage.

*Of* decides who/what gets to access. *To* says what is to be accessed.

edit: if you want the act of accessing, you can use *of*, but that creates some ambiguities and sounds awkwardly. The act is best described without any preposition, as

> Accessing the Computer System remotely is possible through VNC.

Comment: Right, so this is generally wrong: "Team's access of the computer system", and it should be "Team's access to the computer system"?

Comment: I think *access of the computer system* talks mainly about the act of accessing it, while *access to the system* talks mainly about the ability to reach the system.  For example your access of the computer yesterday was illegal. But our firewall should have prevented your access to the system in the first place.

Comment: @hyde: if you really want to word it like that, it's possible, like Jim said. But that's awkward and creates unnecessary ambiguities. Using *to* definitely works well both as act of accessing and as ability to access.